# Save a field as hash and compare it in django

Tags: python, django

I created my own user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name="Mobile Number", max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    security_code = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Security Code",default=create_security_code)
    security_code_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

a user can login with password or security code.

I want it to be like this:

If user wants to login with security code I will create a random security code in my view. text it to them and save the hashed version of the security code in my database. user enters the number from text they received and I compare the hashed version of what user entered with what I have in my database. much like a password.

but I don't want to store security code as plain text in my database. I want to store it like password (hashed).

I found

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
```

which I can use to create a hashed version of security code.

my question is should I write a separate authentication backend or simply write/use a function like check_password that is implanted in AbstractBaseUser?

Comment: "I will text them the security code if needed" would mean that the security code would have to be stored in a way that you could read it so it wouldn't be hashed?

Comment: I will create a random security code in my view. text it to user. save it as hashed. it will expire after some time (hence the security_code_creation )

Comment: Why have a code and a password? If they have to request a code, why not request a new password instead?

Comment: It's a common practice in my country. sometimes users won't even set a password and only use this way to login because it's like a one time password thing.

Comment: Overriding `check_password` is a fine solution, custom backends are usually for authenticating from other sources

Comment: problem is I don't know how it works so I can override it. I read the method and what it calls but I don't know how to tailor it to my needs. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `check_password` in your custom user class could work something like this.

You provide a password or a code when logging in and the method first checks if the value matches the password and if not then it checks if the value matches the security code

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    security_code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Security Code",max_length=128)
    ...
    def set_security_code(self, code):
        self.security_code = make_password(code)
        self.security_code_creation = now()

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        password_matched = super().check_password(raw_password)
        if not password_matched and self.security_code_creation > now() - timedelta(days=1):
            return check_password(raw_password, self.security_code)
        return False
```

Comment: only one more question. what should change about security_code field so it can store hashed value? I know password uses charfield with max_length of 128. should I change my security_code field to that?

Comment: Yes, the existing password field length will be big enough to save the generated hashes

Comment: thanks for your answer and I submitted an edit to your answer for the field.

Comment: No worries, moving the check for security_code to it's own method may be a further improvement so that it can be run and tested in isolation